# Including user data in "new user notification email"

Tags: php, functions, woocommerce-offtopic, user-registration, wp-mail

I'm trying to create a function that sends an email to the admin when a new user registers. I would like the email to contain the users first name, last name, email address, and billing information added via WooCommerce. This is what I have so far, but for some reason $id and $email are the only variables that show up in the email, but nothing else.. What am I doing wrong? lol

```
function admin_notification($user_id) { 
    $user = get_userdata( $user_id );
    $id = $user->id;
    $email = $user->user_email;
    $firstname = $user->first_name;
    $lastname = $user->last_name;
    $phone = get_user_meta($id, 'billing_phone', true);
    $address = get_user_meta($id, 'billing_address_1', true);
    $city = get_user_meta($id, 'billing_city', true);
    $state = get_user_meta($id, 'billing_state', true);
    $zip = get_user_meta($id, 'billing_postcode', true);

    $headers = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8','From: My WordPress Site <noreply@example.com>');
    $message = '<p>'. $firstname .' '. $lastname .' has requested registration to the website. Please verify their account as soon as possible.</p><hr /><p><strong>First Name:</strong> '.$firstname.'<br><strong>Last Name:</strong> '.$lastname.'<br><strong>Email Address:</strong> '.$email.'<br><strong>Phone Number:</strong> '.$phone.'<br><strong>Address:</strong><br>'.$address.', '.$city.' '.$state.' '.$zip.'</p><br><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tr><td><table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tr><td bgcolor="green" style="padding: 12px 18px 12px 18px; -webkit-border-radius:3px; border-radius:3px" align="center"><a href="https://example.com/wp-admin/user-edit.php?user_id='.$id.'" target="_blank" style="font-size: 16px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: normal; color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none; display: inline-block;">Verify User</a></td></tr></table></td></tr></table>';

    wp_mail('admin@example.com', 'New Customer Registration', $message, $headers);
}

add_action('user_register', 'admin_notification', 10, 1);
```

Comment: `$user` instance doesn't have a property `id`, use `ID` instead. `$id = $user->ID;`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how WooCommerce adds these fields, but I suspect it uses add_user_meta after the user_register form or something. 
Try and catch it this way instead:

```
if ( isset( $_POST['first_name'] ) ) {
    $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try using the [wp_new_user_notification](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_new_user_notification/)() function instead. That function is what gets triggered when a new user signs up. My feeling is that all the data you need is going to be available to send in a new message. There's a solid example in the link I posted. I hope this helps!